# A button link to an ImageView with zooming

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to make a link button to an ImageView, it's working but without the zooming, before that, it used to work with zooming only if it was when you run it through your mobile when it's without a link button, I have the code and it's wrong! Does anybody have the same as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.photoview.sample in eclipse?

Edit:

mapslocations.xml

```
<Button
           android:id="@+id/pslook1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="45dp"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Map"
           android:textSize="10sp"
           android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Sites.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Sites extends Activity {
 ImageView imageDetail1;
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
 PointF startPoint = new PointF();
 PointF midPoint = new PointF();
 float oldDist = 1f;
 static final int NONE = 0;
 static final int DRAG = 1;
 static final int ZOOM = 2;
 int mode = NONE;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mapslocations);
  imageDetail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pslook1);
  /**
   * set on touch listner on image
   */
  imageDetail1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
     mode = DRAG;
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

     oldDist = spacing(event);

     if (oldDist > 10f) {
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      midPoint(midPoint, event);
      mode = ZOOM;
     }
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
     mode = NONE;

     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
      matrix.set(savedMatrix);
      matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
        event.getY() - startPoint.y);
     } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
      float newDist = spacing(event);
      if (newDist > 10f) {
       matrix.set(savedMatrix);
       float scale = newDist / oldDist;
       matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
      }
     }
     break;

    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return true;
   }

   @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
  });
 }
}
```

imageview1.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pslook1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/powerstationwallmap" />
```

PagePowerstation.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PagePowerstation extends Activity {

    Button imageview1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so that you are using the code from [Here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). Instead of all the crazy stuff in your sites.java why don't you use a code to change layouts. It has official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). Please go through all the stuff that's inside this documentation, and if still the problem continues, please tell me so that I will edit this to have the code to animate layout changes.

Comment: These two are not helping :) one of them is on "Android Studio"

Comment: The first one, is there away to run it on eclipse?

Comment: I will give you the code to do so in next few minutes.

Comment: If you are wanted to have the android studio files in the eclipse, you first need to create a new application project and copy the files including library.